# React native drawer navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react native and I implemented a simple react native drawer but When I'm running this code in my emulator It gives me a type error.

This is my *drawr.js* code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text,FlatList} from "react-native";
import {Card} from "react-native-paper";
import  {DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

import lessons from './lessons';
import classes from './classes';



class Drawer extends React.Component{


    render() {
        return (
            <MyApp/>
        );
    }
}

const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
    lessons:{
        screen:lessons
    }
})

export default Drawer;
```

Then I got this error:

[image]

How can I fix this error??

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, there are some errors in your code. Try to follow [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/) guide.